# What should I do when receiving testing modules depended module is not completed from developer side

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, build-verification-test

You are getting a build for testing with three modules, but the second module is in the development phase. So what do you do when you need to test the third module, which is dependent on the first and second modules?

For example, getting a build with the student, student mark and student result modules in which the student mark module is pending from the developer side. I need to test student result module but it depends on the student and student marks modules.

What should I do in that situation?

Comment: Can you test the student mark module against *test doubles* of the modules it depends upon?

Comment: Which layer you are testing on? Also is it manually or automated?

Comment: Hello @VishalAggarwal: It manually

Answer (score 2):

It can be tested in any of the below two ways:

1. You can do API Testing of Student Marks and Student Results Module.
2. The developers must have used some kind of dummy Student Marks Data to develop Student Results Module.

   You can use the same or similar dummy data of Student Marks so that you can test Student Results module.

Answer (score 0):

The above situation is often encountered in a software testing company. Below are some of the points which would be helpful in streamlining the process with seamless flow of information.

- We can test the independent and isolated features delivered
- We should not test the features that are dependent on each other as that wold lead to redundant effort
- All the stake holders should be aware of undelivered module so that all parties are aware of the uncompleted task
- Once all the modules are received, integration testing should be done to cross check for any issues that might have been missed.